# column to row in SQL server 2012 using unpivot when don't have any id

Tags: sql-server

I have a table below:-

```
X_Q1 | X_Q2 | X_Q3 | X_Q4 | Y_Q1 | Y_Q2 | Y_Q3 | Y_Q4
---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----
4500 | 3400 | 4600 | 3456 | 3435 | 7643 | 3214 | 43434
```

Script:

```
Create table #Temp
(
    X_Q1 int,
    X_Q2 int,
    X_Q3 int,
    X_Q4 int,
    Y_Q1 int,
    Y_Q2 int,
    Y_Q3 int,
    Y_Q4 int
    )

insert into #Temp values(4500,3400,4600,3456,3435,7643,3214,43434)

select * from #Temp
drop table #Temp
```

**I want the output in below format : -**

```
Code  |     X   |    Y
----  |   ----  |  ---- 
Q1    |   4500  |  3435
Q2    |   3400  |  7643
Q3    |   4600  |  3214
Q4    |   3456  |  43434
```

Comment: Neither PIVOT nor UNPIVOT need any ID. Have you *tried* to write an UNPIVOT query? It's easy to write a query that returns a code and value columns where `Code` is the name of the original colums. UNPIVOT won't parse the column names though. What you posted isn't unpivoting.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT and UNPIVOT don't require an ID or other unique combination of columns. You can easily write:

```
select code, value
from (
        select          
            X_Q1, X_Q2, X_Q3, X_Q4,
            Y_Q1, Y_Q2, Y_Q3, Y_Q4 
        from #temp
    ) p
    unpivot 
    (
        Value for code in 
        (
             X_Q1, X_Q2, X_Q3, X_Q4,
             Y_Q1, Y_Q2, Y_Q3, Y_Q4 
        )
    ) as upvt
```

to unpivot the data into :

```
code    value
X_Q1    4500
X_Q2    3400
X_Q3    4600
X_Q4    3456
Y_Q1    3435
Y_Q2    7643
Y_Q3    3214
Y_Q4    43434
```

Your desired output though requires parsing the code into two separate columns, and *PIVOT*ing again to convert X and Y into columns. PIVOT always works with an aggregation function. In the trivial case where your table has only one row, this doesn't matter.  Most likely though, you need an ID now to avoid aggregating multiple row values into one :

```
with xy as (
    select 
        ID,
        left(code,1) as col, 
        SUBSTRING(code,3,10) as code, 
        value
    from (
            select          
                ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as ID,
                X_Q1, X_Q2, X_Q3, X_Q4,
                Y_Q1, Y_Q2, Y_Q3, Y_Q4 
            from #temp
        ) p
        unpivot 
        (
            Value for code in 
            (
                 X_Q1, X_Q2, X_Q3, X_Q4,
                 Y_Q1, Y_Q2, Y_Q3, Y_Q4 
            )
        ) as upvt
)
select 
    ID,code, [X],[Y]
from xy
PIVOT( 
    sum(value)
    for col in ([X],[Y])
) as pvt
order by ID
```

The row ID is generated by `ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null))`. The `xy` CTE is used to split the code into a `col` field with X,Y values and a new `code` field.

This result is PIVOTed again using X, Y as the new field names.

The result is:

```
ID  code    X       Y
1   Q1      4500    3435
1   Q2      3400    7643
1   Q3      4600    3214
1   Q4      3456    43434
```